# Android Sample missing from download

Tags: android, android-fragments

In this official guide page about fragments http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Example
at the bottom, there is a link to download the entire source code for the described example,

"For more samples using fragments (and complete source files for this example), see the API Demos sample app available in [ApiDemos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/index.html#Fragment) (available for download from the [Samples SDK component](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/get.html))."

but the links takes me to the a samples page that does not contain the aforementioned sample project.

How can I get the code that is missing? Can I find it somewhere else?
I need exactly that code because it fits to my needs and I do not have time to implement another more complicated logic.

Please help.
Thank you

Comment: Open sdk manager, download the samples, then go to android sdk root on you computer and find samples folder...

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however the project is not downloaded in the samples either. It should contain a DetailsFragment.java so I am looking for this file in the whole samples folder with no luck. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

All the old samples were moved under a legacy folder in recent distributions of the samples

For example, what was here:

```
samples/android-14/ApiDemos
```

is now here

```
samples/android-19/legacy/ApiDemos
```

The page you link doesn't make it obvious, but DetailsFragment is an inner class defined in

```
legacy/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentLayout.java
```

rather than in its own class file

This is a case where recursive searches of files and their contents can be very useful, especially if restricted to likely directories.  On an OSX or Linux development system (or even a cygwin or mingw shell) you can use the `find` command to find files, and `grep` with the -r flag to find patterns in any file below a likely directory.

---

The answer to your subsequent question is found with

> grep -A5 -B1 -r a_item *

```
legacy/ApiDemos/res/menu/shortcuts.xml-
legacy/ApiDemos/res/menu/shortcuts.xml:    <item android:id="@+id/a_item"
legacy/ApiDemos/res/menu/shortcuts.xml-        android:alphabeticShortcut="a"
legacy/ApiDemos/res/menu/shortcuts.xml-        android:title="Alvin" />
legacy/ApiDemos/res/menu/shortcuts.xml-
legacy/ApiDemos/res/menu/shortcuts.xml-    <item android:id="@+id/b_item"
legacy/ApiDemos/res/menu/shortcuts.xml-        android:alphabeticShortcut="b"
```

Where `-r` is the recursive flag and `-A` and `-B` tell grep how many lines to print after and before the matching line

This is a definition of an item ID in an xml layout, specified with auto-incrementing syntax.  If you build the ApiDemos project and then examine R.java you will find that each of these names gets assigned to a constant numeric value, in an incrementing list.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was not expecting it to be an inner class so I did not do a thorough search for it.  However, I used the DetailsFragment.java file as a quick example of what I was really looking for, and that was the layouts for the sample projects (because the DetailsFragment.java code can be seen in the tutorial, so no need for finding it).  I was hoping to find the project's folder.  I actually need to know what is this line pointing to: **ft.replace(R.id.a_item, details);**   So where is defined and what is this id `a_item` ?

Comment: I agree with your idea on how to search for it, however, the tutorial talks about fragments and **a_item** should be an id of an item of a layout that will contain a fragment. All I can find is menu items ids. (I already searched for it like this but I thought you might have a different idea on where can I find it)

Comment: The code is "Execute a transaction, replacing any existing fragment with this one inside the frame."  and does:  ` 
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
if (index == 0) {
  ft.replace(R.id.details, details);
} else {
  ft.replace(R.id.a_item, details);
}
`

Comment: I want to recreate the project from the tutorial, and I need the layouts so I can recreate it properly.